# What happened to ePDFview‽

Tags: software-rec, pdf

In my older Fedora installation (It's Fedora 20 right now, but I've been updating it since well before FC18), I'm using a rather minimal PDF viewer, called "ePDFview".
It seems to be gone from more recent repos, though.

The URL in the old package points to http://trac.emma-soft.com/epdfview, the link is dead.

The website of the (former?) developer, [Emma-Soft](http://www.emma-soft.com) doesn't mention ePDFview anywhere. I have difficulty finding information about it. It seemed to me like a rather mature project, but it seems it's been completely abandoned, without anyone really care ing about it. I can't even find the code for it so I can't compile it myself, etc.

Can someone shed a little light on it?

ePDFview was supposed to be a lightweight PDF viewer, "kinda like" Evince, but without Gnome dependencies. If this is *gone for good*, I'd appreciate a suggestion to a similar PDF viewer, that handles like ePDFview, but is not Xpdf, or dependent on Gnome (that would be Evince).

Comment: What happens to most project without maintainers... death.

Comment: IDK, there is a patched version here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/epdfview.html but built on las (old source) of 2011: http://web.archive.org/web/20121222002604/http://trac.emma-soft.com/epdfview/ - else I have been made aware of [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) as of recent which depends on girara and GTK+ : https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/installation/ , it is typically a much more keyboard driven interface then most PDF viewers. (VIM like)

Comment: @user367890 Zathura isn't exactly what I was expecting, but it seems to be a good choice for things like presentations, etc. I've compiled ePDFview from the sources you linked, thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ePDFview has been unmaintained since 2011. I recommend using [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) instead. It is as lightweight as ePDFview but has more features, depends only on the Qt libraries, and copying text from PDFs actually works (it was very buggy on ePDFview).

Comment: Nice. This one also work with forms as I have battled with (ref: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180292/98945) The forms does not look very good, but  it works, which is my main concern. Filled forms can also be saved, as opposed to e.g. the PDF viewer in Chrome.

Comment: Let me give this a little bit of every-day testing, and I'll accept your answer if it ticks the boxes. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: The other thing which epdfview excelled at was large PDFs. eg. I have a 100M reference manual pdf containing ~30,000 pages and epdfview didn't bat an eyelid. qpdfview takes ages to open it and is sluggish.
Actually evince does a decent job of it, although the lack of mouse scroll wheel support is off-putting (maybe because I don't run gnome?).